# Xml output class to generic class

Tags: c#, xml, class

I have a class I found on another post that I'm trying to modify.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Misc
{
  internal class ConfigManager
  {

    private string _sConfigFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, string.Format("{0}.xml", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName));
    private Config m_oConfig = new Config();

    public Config MyConfig
    {
      get { return m_oConfig; }
      set { m_oConfig = value; }
    }

    // Load configuration file
    public void LoadConfig()
    {
      if (System.IO.File.Exists(_sConfigFileName))
      {
        System.IO.StreamReader srReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(_sConfigFileName);
        Type tType = m_oConfig.GetType();
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xsSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(tType);
        object oData = xsSerializer.Deserialize(srReader);
        m_oConfig = (Config)oData;
        srReader.Close();
      }
    }

    // Save configuration file
    public void SaveConfig()
    {
      System.IO.StreamWriter swWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText(_sConfigFileName);
      Type tType = m_oConfig.GetType();
      if (tType.IsSerializable)
      {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xsSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(tType);
        xsSerializer.Serialize(swWriter, m_oConfig);
        swWriter.Close();
      }
    }

  }
}
```

I'd like to pass in an object of type X and have it save. On that same premise, I'd like to pass in a type and have it pass back the object of type X. Right now, it is hard coded to use Config. So, if there is a way to pass in the class object (?) then I'd like it to save it as that object and/or return it of that object.

Is that possible? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generic:

```
internal class ConfigManager<T>
{
    private string _fileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, string.Format("{0}.xml", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName));
    private T _config;
    private XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    public T MyConfig
    {
        get { return _config; }
        set { _config = value; }
    }

    public void LoadConfig()
    {
        if (File.Exists(_fileName))
        {
            using (var reader = File.OpenText(_fileName))
            {
                _config = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SaveConfig()
    {
        using (var writer = File.CreateText(_fileName))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, _config);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var man = new ConfigManager<Foo>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we'd need to make it work with Generics.  So, we start by giving it a type variable, and replace every use of the class `Config` with `T`:

```
 internal class Manager<T>
 {
      private T m_oObj;      // etc
```

Next, I'll just do one method; you can do the rest.  (and I'm removed the explicit namespaces, cuz they're ugly)

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public void LoadConfig<T>()
{
  if (File.Exists(_sConfigFileName))
  {
    var  srReader = File.OpenText(_sConfigFileName);
    var  xsSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    var  oData = xsSerializer.Deserialize(srReader);
    m_oObj = (T)oData;
    srReader.Close();
  }
}
```